# looking for GSM / CDMA call detail record structure

Tags: java, gsm, cdma

i am creating a program in java which will work on call detail records of GSM / CDMA.

i am looking for standard structure of Call detail records used for GSM / CDMA. Can someone help me ?

basically what are all the columns in a call detail record database of GSM / CDMA

Comment: Have you looked at the spec on 3GPP forum? The storage of CDRs might not be standardized but some interface(s) to getting to CDRs might.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a standard structure for CDRs in mobile telephony networks. Find out which network elements you are going to talk to and look at the documentation.

Mobile telephony networks usually deploy a component called "mediation device" which is specialized on parsing and unifying the CDR formats emitted by the various actually deployed network elements. Companys make money with this.

If you are lucky you might get xSV files with vendor-specific columns and column order. If not you might get e.g. ASN.1-encoded or binary files with proprietary formats.

Answer (score 0):

How about this CDR decoder for Ericsson ? http://code.google.com/p/cdr-decoder/